# how to display help icon in VF page for non sobject input

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page which display inputfields from a custom setting. I am using the "Help Text" in the field definition  to display the help text.

Now i also need to show a checkbox which is used to run some javascript code when checked. I need to show help icon beside it.

Is there a way i can implement the help bubble from SF so that the look and feel is not different for this particular field only.

Thanks

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsiMatch">
              <apex:outputLabel value="Match to Accounts"></apex:outputLabel>
              <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!useMatch}" id="chkmatch"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for [apex:pageBlockSectionItem](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm)?

Comment: Oh!! my bad.. i had been checking the documentation for apex:outputlabel. If you can put it as an answer then i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `helpText` attribute of [apex:pageBlockSectionItem](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm) to add the help text in the same format that SalesForce does.

If you need to get the help text that is stored on the field on the SObject then you can use [$ObjectType](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm) to do this. The example below will display the help text from the field `Account.MyField__c`

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem
        helpText="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.MyField__c.InlineHelpText}">
```